Importing Vuetify 3 function useTheme()
I'm trying to implement a dynamic theme switcher on runtime in a Google Apps Script app.
My problem is that I don't know how to import the function called use theme() of vuetify into my Gas project
As explained in Vuetify documentation, I need to use the following function useTheme() :
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-btn @click="toggleTheme">toggle theme</v-btn>
    ...
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useTheme } from 'vuetify'

const theme = useTheme()

function toggleTheme () {
  theme.global.name.value = theme.global.current.value.dark ? 'light' : 'dark'
}
</script>


However I can't figure out how to use the import commant in my Google scrip app project
This is how my project in actually structured :
I have two files
Index.html with Vutify scripts and templates
Code.gs for the backend - only handles Google sheets API
Here is a sample of my index.html
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/3.4.8/vuetify-labs.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-5xeIAXqNP/DWGkolQzdPAL042aA4Lb8SCMy/Ju+9yzvf9SzfsbzICQwYyMrhbN8pG8m0LWhMl9BISpIDs8RquQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
....
</head>

<body>

<script setup>
Import {use theme} from vuetify;
</script>

<script type="module">
    const { createApp } = Vue;
        const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;

        const vuetify = createVuetify({
            theme: {
                defaultTheme: 'dark'
              }
            });
     
        createApp({
            template: "#app-template",

        methods: {

                  toggleTheme () {
                  this.$vuetify.theme.dark = !this.$vuetify.theme.dark;
                    console.log(this.$vuetify.theme.dark);
                  },
}
})
.use(vuetify)
.mount("#app");
</body>

Logs display correctly the Boolean values switching from false to true for the variable 'dark'

The question doesn't include a minimal complete example. Try this:
Code.gs
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
    .setTitle('Demo');
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
    <v-app>
        <v-card
          class="mx-auto"
          width="400"
          append-icon="mdi-human-greeting"
        >
          <template v-slot:title>
            Title
          </template>
          <v-card-text>
            Description
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-app>
    </script>
  <script>
      const { createApp } = Vue;
      const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;
      
      const vuetify = createVuetify(
        {
          theme: {
                defaultTheme: 'dark'
              }
        }
      );
      
      const app = createApp({
        template: "#app-template", 
      })
        .use(vuetify)
        .mount("#app");
  </script>
</body>

</html>

The code of the index.html file was adapted from the answer to  Vuetify instance with cdn not work on vuejs3. I just changed one statement:
From
const vuetify = createVuetify();

To
const vuetify = createVuetify(
        {
          theme: {
                defaultTheme: 'dark'
              }
        }
      ); 


Create a new Google Apps Script project
Set the project title
Replace the boilerplate code in Code.gs by the Code.gs code above.
Add an HTML file, set the file name to 'index'.
Replace the boilerplate code in index.html by the index.html code above.
If you have not done yet save the Google Apps Script project.
Create a new deployment as web app.
Go to the new deployment URL.

You should see something like this:

Once you get this working you could adapt this to your specific needs.
Please remember to use Test Deployment URL to see the last changes an when you be ready deploy a new version.

The import command might be used when using Node.js to install and build your web app using NPM modules for Vue and Vuetify. This could be done when creating a Google Apps Script web application locally or a more complete online IDE and using the Google Apps Script API. CLASP might be handy with this.
import might be also used on client-side code. One opetion is to use the URL instead of the module name. Another options is to use importmaps
Related Q/A

How to use ES6 import (client-side JS)
importing a package in ES6: "Failed to resolve module specifier "vue""
I want to use Vue 3 without build and without CDN

References

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap

